# scroll with mouse wheel and mouse movement

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I try to make a gallery that I can move in its content with mouse wheel or with mouse movement.

I used the following script for mouse movement http://valums.com/files/2009/menu/final.htm and for mouse wheel I use [Mouse Wheel Plugin](http://brandonaaron.net/code/mousewheel/docs).

Separately they work great but when I try to combine them I have some problems. Check the following demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/A93mF/

As you can see partially works but, and I say partially because when I use mouse wheel to scroll it's ok, but when I move a bit the cursor then returns in the previous position.

How can I make it so, if I scroll and then move the cursor to continue normally the scrolling instead of return in the previous position?

Any solution is acceptable (change javascript[jQuery], html structure, plugin or whatever)

Comment: I can't provide an answer, I can provide a hint however: You are recalculating the position every mousemove and in this you do not take the scrollwheel into account, basically resetting the position.

Comment: What are you using?Firefox?On chrome the mousewheel has a really strange behaviour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrote the mouse movement script and now I think is works fine and in Chrome also (thanks @Nicola Peluchetti ) For anyone interested can check the following demo: http://jsfiddle.net/A93mF/3/